# passing two comma separated strings into an en var in bash

Tags: bash, variables

I'm not really sure what's the proper way to pass two comma separated strings to an environment variable in bash.

I would like to pass to the env var `TOKEN` something like this (two comma separated strings)

```
TOKEN=${API_TOKEN_ONE:-<default_string>}, ${API_TOKEN_TWO:-<default_string>}
```

Is that correct or I should pass it as a list?

Comment: Wrap it in double quotes. But it depends on what you want to do with it. Do you want to use it as an array in bash?

Comment: That's not an environment variable, it's a shell variable. It doesn't become an environment variable until you `export` it.

Comment: There are tonnes of questions on [Shell Param Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) here in Stack Overflow. This is a clear case of the op not searching the similar questions.

Answer (score 2):

As written:

```bash
TOKEN=${API_TOKEN_ONE:-<default_string>}, ${API_TOKEN_TWO:-<default_string>}
```

This creates a TOKEN variable containing "${API_TOKEN_ONE:-<default_string>}," and puts it into the execution environment of the "${API_TOKEN_TWO:-<default_string>}" **command**.

Refer to [Simple Command Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Simple-Command-Expansion) in the bash manual.

As commented, values containing whitespace need to be quoted

```
TOKEN="${API_TOKEN_ONE:-<default_string>}, ${API_TOKEN_TWO:-<default_string>}"
```

If your intent is to use the TOKEN variable as some kind of CSV record, don't put a space after the comma.

> Is that correct or I should pass it as a list?

Note that arrays are not available in every shell, and that environment variables cannot be arrays.

Comment: So if I want to add two strings into the env vat TOKEN I need to delete the whitespace and keep the quotation?

Comment: @peterpan You need to delete the whitespace OR double-quote the string. You can also do both, but you don't need to. However, I'd consider using double-quote around anything this complex to be a good idea on general principles, whether or not you remove the whitespace. I'd also recommend double-quotes when you use the variable (i.e. `"$TOKEN"`). BTW, I wouldn't think of this as the variable containing two strings; variables always hold single strings, but what you're doing is storing two *values* (delimited by a comma) in that single string.